# Getting SSL encryption error in Chrome on CodeIgniter site

Tags: codeigniter, ssl, ssl-certificate, codeigniter-2

I've got a site I've built in CodeIdgniter. I have an SSL certificate installed. I updated my htaccess file to [this](https://gist.github.com/1637244). The page i'm encrypted [is here](https://avitransportationservices.com/welcome/buynow).

Here's the error I'm [seeing in Chrome](http://l.jshultz.co/y2NS0U).

It says that some of the items aren't being encrypted but when i look at the console i don't see any problems?

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not getting any errors in Google Chrome .  Just make sure every static asset like , css , js, images is being served via https.

Comment: It looks like part of the problem was caching. After an hour everything just resolved itself.